# Monaca (Cordova) BarcodeScanner won't cancel

Tags: ios, cordova, barcode-scanner, cordova-plugins, monaca

I'm using Monaca to develop an iOS app that uses the BarcodeScanner Cordova plugin. In the Monaca debugger it works fine, but when I build the app and run it on its own I cannot cancel the barcode scanner. It triggers, shows the camera, and shows the "Cancel" button at the bottom of the screen, but pressing the cancel button does nothing. In the debugger though it works as expected. It scans barcodes fine in both cases.

What might be causing it to work differently when it's built?

Comment: Hi, 
I did try to create an app with BarcodeScanner plugin. But it works fine either in Monaca debugger or the built app. Have you tried building it again?

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me! I was using a iPad 2 with iOS 8.2 and the cancel button wasn't working. Making the changes outlined in the 6th comment down in the post at this link did the trick.

https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner/issues/162

Comment: This would be a much more helpful answer if you actually described the changes suggested in the comment, since that link may break over time.